# I am creating my own shortcut bar but can't manage the user access

Tags: 7

I am creating a shortcut bar something like below, but unfortuntly it show up despite my wish that I could hide it for anonymous and administrator users/role. I want to display it for editor roles only. How do I achieve this? Thanks

```
function shortcat_permission() {
  return array(
    'administer shortcat' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer shortcats'),
      'restrict access' => TRUE,
    ),
  );
}

function shortcat_page_alter(&$page) {
       $page['page_top']['#pre_render'][] = 'shortcat_toolbar_pre_render';
   }



function shortcat_renderables() {

  $shortcut_set = array();
  $shortcut_set['my_list'][] = array("#markup" =>"<ul>");
  $shortcut_set['my_list'][] = array("#markup" =>"<li><a href='node/add' class='shlinks'>".t('Add Content')."</a></li>");
  $shortcut_set['my_list'][] = array("#markup" =>"<li><a href='admin/content' class='shlinks'>".t('Find Content')."</li>");
  $shortcut_set['my_list'][] = array("#markup" =>"</ul>");
  return $shortcut_set; 
}


function shortcat_toolbar_pre_render() {
  $links = shortcat_renderables();

  $links['#attached'] = array('css' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'shortcat') . '/shortcat.css'));
  $links['#prefix'] = '<div class="toolbar-shortcats">';
  $links['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  return $links;
}
```

I know you can make use of:

```
global $user;
  if ($user->uid)  {
display it here...
{
```

but this won't make the user access right accesible in People > Permissions

Comment: did you try simple_access module? I think it may help you here.

Comment: The idea was to learn how hook_permission works :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're defining a permission you can make use of the [`user_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_access/7) function to check that the user is allowed to access the shortcut menu. You can actually then use the `#access` key on your render array to denote whether or not it should be shown:

```
function shortcat_toolbar_pre_render() {
  $links = shortcat_renderables();

  $links['#attached'] = array('css' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'shortcat') . '/shortcat.css'));
  $links['#prefix'] = '<div class="toolbar-shortcats">';
  $links['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  $links['#access'] = user_access('administer shortcat');

  return $links;
}
```

That code will deny access for anyone who doesn't have the `administer shortcat` permission. All you need to do is make sure the permission is ticked for the editor role in the admin permissions page.

It's worth bearing in mind that `user_access()` wil always return `TRUE` if you are logged in as the super user (ID:1). If you need this to be different then the easiest way would be to check that the user physically has the `editor` role assigned to their account:

```
global $user;
if (!in_array('edit', $user->roles)) {
  $links['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Clive, i couldn't make the hook_permission and #access works. The only thing that help me fix the problem was this piece of code:   global $user;
  if ($user->uid>1) {
         $page['page_top']['#pre_render'][] = 'shortcat_toolbar_pre_render';
  }

Answer (score 1):

I got similar functionality by using the [Shortcuts Per Role module](https://www.drupal.org/project/shortcutperrole), permissions, tweaking of the theme's page.tpl.php file and a little jQuery.

I wanted to have the stock shortcut bar visible for a few roles with shortcut sets assigned by role, but I only wanted the administrative toolbar visible for the administrator role.  I set the permissions for the roles I wanted to have the shortcut bar to be able to "Use the administration toolbar", created shortcut sets and assigned them in the Shortcuts Per Role settings.

In my theme's page.tpl.php file, I added the following snippet to pass the current user's roles to be used in my js.  Replace 'path to js file' with the actual path to your js file.

```
drupal_add_js(array('Theme' => array('role' => $GLOBALS['user']->roles)), 'setting');

drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'Theme') . 'path to js file', 'file');
```

In my theme's js file, I added the following code:

```
Drupal.behaviors.Theme = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var roleArr = Drupal.settings.Theme.role;
      var isAdmin = false;
      for (role in roleArr) {
        if (roleArr[role] == 'administrator') {
            isAdmin = true;
        }
      }
      if (isAdmin == false) {
        $('.toolbar-menu').remove();
      }
    }
};
```

This basically just removes the admin toolbar unless the logged in user is an administrator and leaves the shortcut bar intact.